# Logitech MX Master 2S Mouse not discovered by Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth, mouse, logitech

Around two weeks ago, my mouse stopped being discovered via Bluetooth. My system is a dual boot with Windows 10 and it works just fine on that OS as well as with my laptop dual boot on both the Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 side.

I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong as it seems like Bluetooth is functioning normally on the machine. It just doesn't see my mouse. The motherboard is a ROG STRIX X570-E Gaming Wifi II and I don't see any specific drivers for Ubuntu on the product site (though there are drivers for windows 10/11). Could this simply be a driver issue? I've attempted to update all drivers possible and have looked at `rfkill`, `lsusb`, and `hciconfig` and nothing seems out of order to me. I'd post those outputs here, but I don't know how to copy and paste the terminal output without a mouse.

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated as this is preventing me moving forward with my dissertation research!

Comment: 1 method: from command line do `rfkill >> tmp/file && lsusb >>/tmp/file && hciconfig >>/tmp/file`  then windows keys, gedit, control o to open files. Use tab to go to other locations. /tmp and open the file. Control A, Control C and do a control V in the question. The WHOLE of gnome is designed by default to work with a keyboard and no mouse or touchpad. Just got the press to correct keys ;-)

Comment: To test BT: do you have a 2nd BT device? If that connects you can proof it is not a hardware problem. 2nd: you can also check a live session and see if the mouse works there. That would also prove it is not a hardware issue. Drivers: doubt it, Mice use a generic driver. The software for windows tends to be extra tools that are not really needed. Mice in Windows work without it too.

Comment: Change the mouse battery?

Comment: This is not a user forum, but a Q&A site collecting valuable questions and answers useful to Ubuntu user. So please edit the title and have it reflect your actual question. Once you graduated, your current title will be outdated.